# How to optimize the retrieval of images from a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am retrieving images from a database and displaying using Datalist, but the image loading time is high so need help to optimize it. Here is my code:

```
public byte[] GetPicture(string Id, string state)
{
    byte[] picData = null;

    try
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            this.openConnection();
        strGetImage = string.Format(strGetImage, Id);
        OleDbCommand oledbCommand = new OleDbCommand(strGetImage, con);
        picData = (byte[])(oledbCommand.ExecuteScalar());

               }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
    return picData;
  }
```

Comment: Guys, rather than slating the question - can you try helping or at least post a comment so the question can be improved.

Comment: What size are the images? Is this live or development?

Comment: @RobbieDee:- Thnx Buddy... its live db & image sizes are generally 10-20 kb... but the no. of images to display is 60

Comment: The code looks fairly standard so I suspect the problem lies elsewhere. What is the load on the DB server like? Any idea how many concurrent users you have? You might want to speak to the DBA about isolation levels as by default, even a select can cause a DB lock.

Comment: The website hasn't gone live yet but will be live in a day or so, so there is very less load on DB right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save Images in some local folder on your drive and then save their paths in DataBase.When You want to retrieve,You can get path from DB and read Image File from that path.

```
byte[] img = Files.readAllBytes(Path);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the images do not change, so adding a cache will save you the roundtrips to the database. Or saving the images on disk instead of the database will also help.